# Shell [sic] we post rebus #8?

Tags: rebus

It's ironic that the word in question contradicts the images.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this fits, but....

> Clam-Oar, Clamor?

Comment: Incredible!  Your brain paddles fast, Quant!